# ` those backticks don't work if there's a space `

Tags: bug, markdown

Markdown:

```
` those backticks don't work if there's empty space `
```

Rendered:

`those backticks don't work if there's empty space`

Markdown:

```
`those backticks work without space`
```

Rendered:

`those backticks work without space`

At least in the comment section of webapps.SE, they seem to be working here in post. maybe a bug? I guess in any comment section

Comment: ` those quotes dont work if there's empty space ` 

`those quotes  work without  space`

Comment: wowwww that bug is alive from the beginning of SE and no one knew how to fix it! I didn't bother searching for dupe since I assumed if they know about it they would have fixed it. I don't know what's worse, the existence of the bug or the fact that no one can fix it

Comment: @Cai untested but something like this should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704104/remove-white-spaces-from-string-between-comma-and-any-letter the question is for commas but anything else should work. Removing spaces is trivial task, unless I'm missing something. I don't know how they want to do it, but I know that everything can be fixed, unless you're not the one who created the software. For instance many things are impossible in wordpress, but everything is possible for custom made software.